# posting photo on wall facebook with online path

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post images on wall when choosing it, i'm working with PHP SDK,
So images are fine when using the absolute path of the image like ( "C://...") 
But i want to post online image under a server like ( "http:mywebsite.com/image.jpg" )

the URL is like : localhost/facebook/image.jpg , i tried also another image combiboilersleeds.com/images/online/online-0.jpg

I tried it but it doesn't work I'm getting error :

CurlException: 26: couldn't open file ""

What should i do ? 
I'm using the code below :

```
      $image['image'] = '@'. $data["path"];
      $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
      $img = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $image);
```

$data is the array in which i conserve images absolute paths.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a sufficient error description, please debug your code. the api usually returns something.

Comment: CurlException: 26: couldn't open file ""

Comment: well, what is the url exactly? please edit your question instead of adding relevant info in comments.

Comment: the URL is like : http://localhost/facebook/image.jpg , i tried also another image http://combiboilersleeds.com/images/online/online-0.jpg

Comment: Got it , I supposed to use  $image['url'] = ' MyURL' ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it , I supposed to use $image['url'] = ' MyURL' for uploading an url instead of   $image['image'] = '@'. $data["path"];